# How to get ID for onRowSelected event for asp.net webforms jqGrid?

Tags: jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

I have implemented server side jqgrid with the following code

```
        <trirand:JQGrid ID="jQGrid1" runat="server" OnDataRequesting="jQGrid1_DataRequesting" Height="220" LoadOnce="false"  OnRowSelecting="jQGrid1_RowSelecting">
            <AppearanceSettings ShowRowNumbers="true" />
            <Columns>
                <trirand:JQGridColumn DataField="AppId" HeaderText="Application ID" PrimaryKey="True" Width="100"  />
                <trirand:JQGridColumn DataField="Name" HeaderText="Application Name" Width="200"/>
                <trirand:JQGridColumn DataField="Link" Width="280" />
            </Columns>
            <PagerSettings ScrollBarPaging="true" PageSize="20" NoRowsMessage="scroll down to fetch records" CurrentPage="1"/>
        </trirand:JQGrid>
```

But for the onRowSelected Event when i check in my c# code i was getting  selected index as some random values like jqg11,jqg25,....
why is it happening .What should i do to make one of my column  to set as key when selected 
I have checked below options

```
jQGrid1.SelectedRow
e.RowKey
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't use commercial version of jqGrid, thus the code which you posted say me almost nothing. Nevertheless the reason of ids like `jqg11` and `jqg25` are typically errors in **filling of the grid**. jqGrid requires to assign `id` attribute to every row. So the server response should contains the id values. The exact information depends on the format of input data which you chosen, from the version of jqGrid which you use and from other options like `id` property of `jsonReader` or the existence of `key: true` property in one column of `colModel`. I recommend you to verify the JSON/XML data which you use to fill the grid. Probably you ddidn't specified correctly the `id` values.